# FileDepot upload file sizes restriction

Tags: files

I am using the [filedepot](http://drupal.org/project/filedepot) module. With this module I am able to upload files. I want to allocate space for "uploading files" to individual registered users basing on user roles.

Is it possible? How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that is possible with [filedepot](http://drupal.org/project/filedepot) without patching the module. However it **is** readily available within the [IMCE module](http://drupal.org/project/imce) if you are able to change modules.  From the project page:

> - Basic file operations: upload, delete
> - Image(jpg, png, gif) operations: resize, create thumbnails, preview
> - Support for private file system
> - Configurable limits for user roles: file size per upload, directory
>     quota, file extensions, and image dimensions
> - Personal or shared folders for users
> - Permissions per directory
> - Ftp-like directory navigation
> - File sorting by name, size, dimensions, date
> - Tabbed interface for file operations
> - Keyboard shortcuts(up, down, insert(or enter), delete, home, end,
>     ctrl+A, R(esize), T(humbnails), U(pload)).
> - Built-in support for inline image/file insertion into textareas
> - Multiple file selection(using ctrl or shift)
> - Ajax file operations
> - Themable layout using tpl files

For a better idea of what you are looking at, take a look at a [screenshot of filedepot](http://drupal.org/node/770702).

Everything you need is already built in to [IMCE](http://drupal.org/project/imce).